# Inconsistency in java.util.concurrent.Future?

Tags: java, concurrency, future

For the sake of argument, let's say I'm implementing `Future` for a task which is not cancelable.  The [Java 6 API doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) says:

> After [`cancel()`] returns, subsequent calls to `isDone()` will always return `true`.
>
> [`cancel()`] returns `false` if the task could not be cancelled, typically because it has already completed normally

It also says:

> [`isDone()`] returns `true` if this task completed.

But what if my cancellation fails not because the task is already completed, but because it simply cannot be cancelled?  Is there a way out of this contradiction (other than making my uncancelable task cancelable and sidestepping it altogether)?

Comment: You missed the qualification of "completed": `Completion may be due to normal termination, an exception, or cancellation -- in all of these cases, this method will return true. `

Comment: It's also relevant to cite `Future.cancel(boolean)`: *This attempt will fail if the task has already completed, has already been cancelled, or could not be cancelled **for some other reason**.*  So it seems legit to fail to cancel for whatever reason you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem like the doc should say

> After `cancel()` returns *true*, subsequent calls to `isDone()`...

The Javadocs are often flat-out wrong and contradictory, and Sun has often not even bothered to fix them even after 10 years.  Careful testing should always supplement the docs.

Comment: I would not rely on output of "careful testing" as an extension to the documentation. If the specification isn't specific, other implementations (this includes further versions of the same VM) may behave differently. Strick to the spec if you want to be safe.

Comment: @Romain: I don't see how you can say that sticking to the spec is safe when the reference (and de facto standard) implementation doesn't conform to the spec.  Your program will be wrong in the 99% case, but maybe right for an environment that nobody will ever use.

Comment: I think 99% of times is a broad dramatization. The spec is usually not wrong, but sometimes very poorly phrased and imprecise.

Comment: @Romain: I did not say (or mean to say) that the spec is wrong 99% of the time, I'm saying when the spec differs from Sun's implementation, and you choose to follow the spec, your program will be wrong in 99% of environments, because Sun's implementation is the de facto standard.